# Deploy and test application on device

Tags: ios, xcode, ipod

How do I run my XCode project on my iPod touch?

I am a developer, my iPod runs iOS 5.0.1, but I can not figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need an iOS Developer License (99$/year) and then, you need to follow these steps

1) [Deploying iphone apps real devices](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/deploying-iphone-apps-real-devices)

OR

2) [Testing Apps on the Devices](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Testing_Apps_on_the_iPhone_%E2%80%93_Developer_Certificates_and_Provisioning_Profiles)

Answer (score 1):

Now, you can test apps on real device without enrolling into `Apple's $99 developer program`. You only need to have `free apple ID`. *Refer* [Apple Docs - Free On-Device Development](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_7_0.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015242-SW11).

[image: Screenshot for documentation]