# How to test iOS app on device with USB cable

Tags: iphone, testing, usb, device

I created the certificate and provisioning profile, but I cannot figure out how to get the app onto the device. I have an iphone connected to the computer and don't know what my next step is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deploy and test application on device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9369191/deploy-and-test-application-on-device)

Answer (score 2):

Go to xCode and choose:
Window -> Organizer

In this window you will be able to find your device.
Click your device and press "Use for development" :-)

Answer (score 0):

open xcode now go Window ->Organizer copy attached device identifier(UIID) like as (3133a6e14322a59b4f4d762fa0fcc0f7efe0lb24).

Goto https://developer.apple.com/account/overview.action

Choose Device add new device(click + sign) give device name and past device identifier.

Now go to provisional profile.

Edit provisional profile for both development and distribution. check new added device.

Again go to Window -> Organizer->provisional profiles delete all and refresh it(clicking refresh button on right bottom).

New downloaded profiles appears with green dot.

Next open your project goto Build Setting->code signing identity choose your provisional for iPhone development or distribution.

Hope it works.